# Подключение и захват вывода запущенного ранее процесса Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, ос, subprocess

Хочу сделать Python-скрипт, который открывает Powershell в виде отдельного окна, вводит туда команду посредством keyboard.write, и на основе ответа Powershell на эту команду, вводит последующие данные (пароли, ip-адреса и.т.п.).
Обязательное условие, чтобы после завершения работы скрипта окно Powershell оставалось открытым, чтобы я мог выполнять последующие манипуляции вручную.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Через os.startfile Powershell отлично запускается в отдельном окне, как мне нужно, но при этом нет возможности прочитать вывод.
методы subprocess.run или subprocess.Popen позволяют запускать Powershell, вводить туда команды и считывать весь его вывод, но только в консоли Python, а мне нужно, чтобы параллельно было открыто отдельное окно Powershell, на котором все эти действия также отображаются.

Могу ли я через subprocess(или другими методами) НЕ запустить, а подключиться у уже запущенному через os.startfile процессу Powershell? Либо как-то запустить Powershell сразу и с отдельным окном и с захватом вывода?